# Python can't use airflow.providers.google module

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I've been practicing airflow dags for few days already. And now I want to test airflow dags with my google cloud bucket. For this I need to install apache-airflow-providers-google package.

So I typed in command pip install apache-airflow-providers-google
And then, to make sure I've installed apache-airflow-providers-google I've typed pip list

In my point of view, It is installed successfully

[image: Pip list]

But when I try to import airflow.providers.google it doesnt appear into my VScode

[image: VScode import module]

All providers have been installed successfully, but not google. I've already created another env, but none have worked. Can someone explain to me why airflow.providers.google is not working?

PS: Airflow version is 2.4.2 and python version is 3.8.12

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is still an issue with your environment.

The Python you're using while installing the library would be different than what's getting used in your IDE.

In your terminal, if you do `which python`, it will tell you which python is getting used. This python would be different from the one from your virtual environment getting used in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

To work correctly in your local environement, I recommend you using a virtual env for your project.

To correctly manage the `Python` versions on your machine, you can install the [PyEnv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) tool.

**Go to the root folder of your project and create a virtual env :**

```bash
python3 -m venv <virtual-environment-name>

python3 -m venv my-env
```

`my-env` is the name of the virtual env.

**Activate this venv :**

```bash
source my-env/bin/activate
```

**Add this dependency in your `requirements.txt` file :**

```
apache-airflow[gcp]==2.4.2
```

You can directly download the extra packages for `Google Cloud` with this syntax.

**Run the following command :**

```bash
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You can also use the [PipEnv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) to automate the creation of a virtual env :

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[dev-packages]
pytest = "==6.1.2"

[packages]
apache-airflow = { version = "==2.4.2", extras = ["gcp"] }

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

With `PipEnv` or `Poetry`, you can separate the testing packages and the applicative package.

I also share with you this video from my GCP Youtube channel, that shows an [example of local Python project with PyEnv and PipEnv](https://youtu.be/5sOp6y5499A)